# insertBefore multiple classes

Tags: jquery, syntax

What's the correct syntax to insert multiple different classes with jquery. What if I wanted to insert `.one` `.two` and `.three` before the `#container`.

```
$(".one").insertBefore($('#container'));
```

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like with CSS selectors:

```
$('.one, .two, .three').insertBefore($('#container'));
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Super quick! Will tick in 12 mins.